# How to eliminate the telephone emoji in unicode?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, scrapy

During web scraping and after getting rid of all html tags, I got the black telephone character \u260e in unicode (☎). But unlike [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266842/character-u260e) I do want to get rid of it too.

I used the following regular expressions in Scrapy to eliminate html tags:

```
pattern = re.compile("<.*?>|&nbsp;|&amp;",re.DOTALL|re.M)
```

Then I tried to match \u260e and I think I got caught by [the backslash plague](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague). I tried unsuccessfully this patterns:

```
pattern = re.compile("<.*?>|&nbsp;|&amp;|\u260e",re.DOTALL|re.M)
pattern = re.compile("<.*?>|&nbsp;|&amp;|\\u260e",re.DOTALL|re.M)
pattern = re.compile("<.*?>|&nbsp;|&amp;|\\\\u260e",re.DOTALL|re.M)
```

None of this worked and I still have \u260e as an output.
How can I make this disappear?

Comment: As mentioned on your link, raw strings are the antidote to backslash plague.  It may not be the most relevant thing here, but keep it in mind.

Comment: In line with @Rubens answer, the problem you're facing is that regular strings *aren't* properly unicode encoded, unless you prefix the with `u`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Python 2.7.3, the following works fine for me:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(u"<.*?>|&nbsp;|&amp;|\u260e",re.DOTALL|re.M)
s = u"bla ble \u260e blo"
re.sub(pattern, "", s)
```

Output:

```
u'bla ble  blo'
```

As pointed by @Zack, this works due to the fact that the string is now in unicode, i.e., the string is already converted, and the sequence of characters `\u260e` is now the -- probably -- two bytes used to write that little black phone ☎ (:

Once both the string to be searched and the regular expression have the black phone itself, and not the sequence of characters `\u260e`, they both match.

Comment: Good answer but you should maybe emphasize that the key difference here is those `u` prefixes on all the strings, i.e. operating on Unicode rather than byte strings.

Comment: I guess that u prefix made some difference. It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If your string is already unicode, there's two easy ways. The second one will affect more than just the ☎, obviously.

```
>>> import string                                   
>>> foo = u"Lorum ☎ Ipsum"                          
>>> foo.replace(u'☎', '')                           
u'Lorum  Ipsum'                                     
>>> "".join(s for s in foo if s in string.printable)
u'Lorum  Ipsum'
```

- [Remove non-ascii characters but leave periods and spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/python-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces) for more information about `string.printable`
- [The SHORTEST way to remove multiple spaces in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/the-shortest-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string-in-python) if you don't want multiple whitespaces.

Comment: Writing that ☎ character directly on terminal it worked, but not on my pipeline. Replacing it by \u260e worked better. Thank you for those 2 additional hints :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try with BeatifulSoup, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236437/python-unicodeencodeerror-how-can-i-simply-remove-troubling-unicode-characters), with something like

```
soup = BeautifulSoup (html.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```